# Tips for searching effectively on Stack Overflow - novice developer training

Tags: discussion, search, education

As part of a course/class for **extremely** junior and novice developers, I'd like to provide them with some material on how to search on Stack Overflow effectively.

What I'm looking for is *not* the [technical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to search (i.e., negate a term with the minus sign). Rather it's for something about the 'art' of searching effectively on Stack Overflow (or the web in general) for concrete coding/technical answers.

An example of such a search tip could be "*try to search for the error message you're seeing*".

Any advice, idea, link to a blog post, link to an article, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: an interesting quest indeed, if we can pretend the fixation on Stack Overflow does not exist. The last thing someone wants to do is throw away a large chunk of the web when looking for information (or asking for help). IMO I don't think that this has really been written about all that much. A large part of it boils down to perseverance really, not following rules and guidelines. Do go to page 2 and 3 of the search results. Do rearrange your keywords. Do follow links. Do read for more than half a minute.

Comment: Good advice here but too bad, people will probably not search for how to search before asking.

Comment: @Gimby As a contributor to Stack Overflow, I want the answers to my question to exist on SO where relevant to the site.  While it's important to search beyond it to determine a good solution, often if I don't find it on SO part of my process is that once I've found the solution, I'll write a self-answered question on Stack Overflow to help both others and future me.  Starting the search specifically to SO is one way to achieve that.

Comment: Very interesting/useful Question/Concept/Idea, ... that I actually downvoted for its "Gimme-Ze-Codez" Style of asking, with no or very little "Research Effort"... You (@OP) must have done some "Thinking" already, I would think/hope, it would have been "nice" to mention those Ideas... (OK, "*Search on Error Message*" is (a good) one...) // Would be nice in the end if this Thread gets linked to from the FAQ/Help Center, I already like the (first) Answer...

Comment: @Gimby - I wrote the question about SO because we're in the meta forum of SO. In practice, you're right of course - the real question is how to find technical answers on the web.

Comment: @chivracq - I purposely didn't include my few (not very intelligent) thoughts about it, as I wanted to keep the question short and avoid constraining the thinking process of others. I will add a couple of notes in an answer.

Comment: I have to really think what I personally do to find my information, it is kind of automatic nowadays. Comes with experience. One thing that is crystal clear is that I search very differently depending on what I'm after; generic information/understanding, or a specific problem. So there is not one set of guidelines to rule them all. There is some glue though because "Don't fixate on making a problem go away, try to learn enough to understand where a problem comes from" is definitely on the board.

Comment: @Roy2012, yeah-hum..., that's an (at the first sight understandable) "Approach", but you could have mentioned it then... And as soon as Users start commenting with Tips and Ideas + posting more structured Answers, the "later" Readers also get "biased" by the previous Comments/Answers/Tips already posted... (Or all Answers should be posted as 'Spoiler Blocks' (which probably wouldn't be very "practical"...), to allow for "Fresh Thinking" for everybody...)

Comment: I think this post has the potential of becoming really helpful since SE has a steep learning curve and some times you hit some rocks in the process.

Comment: @Trilarion maybe most people won't, but their students will if they insist on it.

Comment: @S.Dre Sorry for me being rather pessimistic. From experience I think that not enough people will read it. It's definitely not Roy2012's fault. It's just the way things are.

Comment: Yep @Trilarion. And I must say, I kind of understand why. It's like EULAs. They are not meant to be read in reality. People nowadays are bombarded with info and have little spare time to do that. Only people really involved in SE would read it.

Comment: This might also be on topic  in [cseducators.se]. From their [tour](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/tour), "Computer Science Educators Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those involved in the field of teaching Computer Science."

Comment: @Rubén indeed, I've asked a related question there before: [What things aren't obvious about reading documentation? How can I explain to others how to do it?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7328)

Answer (score 73):

Here are some basic things that come to my mind. This list is not exhaustive and it depends on the actual use-cases but I hope it helps a bit.

### Use external search engines

Stack Overflow posts are optimized for search engines. If you want to look for Stack Overflow results only, you can include `site:stackoverflow.com` (at least if you use Google) in your search like [Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) mentioned in the comments of your question.

If you are looking for source code, you might as well add a prefix like `GitHub` or `site:github.com` to your query (since *source code* is often provided via GitHub). This is similar for other platforms.

I personally use Google (other search engines work as well) and not the Stack Overflow search most of the time for finding solutions to my problems. This will also show you other resources like bug trackers or various forums (or other Stack Exchange sites :)).

### Search for keywords

Instead of typing in the whole question (which doesn't yield bad results in many cases with modern search engines), type in keywords associated with your problem. For example, if you want to know how to exit Vim, you could search for `exit Vim` or `exit Vim with saving` instead of typing `How do I exit Vim? I'm cannot find a save button`. Also keywords like `example`, `crash` or `bluescreen` can be useful if you are looking for those things.

Your search query doesn't need to be grammatically correct.

#### Exception/Error messages

If you are trying to fix an exception/error, include the message of the error (e.g., the first line if you have a stack trace or similar). You could also try including the whole error text if you are using an external search (try both).

#### Include topics/technologies/programming languages

If your problem is related to some program, topic, technology, programming language, framework or similar, include the name of that that in your search.

##### Stack Overflow search: include tags but also try without

If you are using the Stack Overflow search and there is a tag for that, try including it using the tag syntax (`[yourtag]`).

Since that will only give you questions matching the tag, you should also try the same search without the tag or with other combinations of tags and without any tags. Note that each Stack Overflow question can only have five tags so searching for more than two tags at once may not yield any results.

### Remove quotation marks

Many search engines (like Google and the Stack Overflow search) use double quotes for exact matches. If your error message or similar contains those (for example for paths on your disk), you might as well remove them, especially if they have content that may be specific to you (e.g., a path with your username). You might as well omit specific stuff like that from your search (if it isn't relevant for solving your problem).

### Just search, nothing bad can happen

If you are unsure about anything, just search it. Try out multiple (lots) of (different) search queries and you might get the results you need with some.

Don't just look at the first result, but also others.

Search, search, search.

### NOT operator

Many search engines include a NOT-operator. If you only find results about one thing you are not interested about (because it has the same name or similar), add a negated version (e.g. `-uninteresting_word`) of that to your search so that results including that are filtered out.

### Use external tools if they help you

There seems to be a [blog post about some tool named `CROKAGE`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/14/crokage-a-new-way-to-search-stack-overflow/) ([link to the tool](http://www.isel.ufu.br:9000/)). If there are tools that help you, you might as well use them. Note that it currently only seems to work for Java questions.

I personally don't use that tool but it might be worthy of trying.

### People will get better

As with many things, getting used to those things and gaining experience will help you in getting better with searching for problems.

Comment: About the "*Search for keywords*" Section, using the *right* Keywords is also "crucial"... When searching for `a loop in a loop` for example, one might need to read a few Threads before identifying `nested`/`inner`/`outer` as the *magic Keywords*... Same with `array of array(s)`, => `multidimensional`/`matrix`/`jagged` will yield more precise Results...

Comment: "Stack Overflow search: include tags" I would remove this entire section. No one knows what tags are relevant and what aren't. If you use tags as keywords, you will be on a world of pain.

Comment: @Braiam Maybe restrict it to language tags. Those are always relevant, and a large majority of questions is tagged with the correct programming language.

Comment: I think the first point can't be emphasized enough. I've been a member for far over a decade and I have not even once used the internal search (did we even have one back in the naughts?). Google spends Knuth knows how much money each year to improve its algorithms, SO competing with them doesn't make much sense. And as a user I don't want to have to learn a slightly different advanced syntax. After finding a promising result with google, the "related posts" are quite often exceedingly useful though.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, but I wouldn't trust it anyways. Stick to actual search engines and avoid SO search unless you know what you are searching for.

Comment: If copying error messages out of an IDE, in addition to quotation marks you often need to clean out things like a reference to where the error occurred.  `C:\git\theproject\subfolder\subsubfolder\filename.ext:1234` is useful to you if you're sharing where the problem occurred with a collaborator; but just noise to Google.

Comment: I did write about that ("You might as well omit specific stuff like that from your search (if it isn't relevant for solving your problem).")

Comment: The `site:` prefix works for DuckDuckGo as well.

Comment: One of the problems with the search engines is that they are very reluctant to return results from 2008 and 2009 (which contain all of the canonical questions to all the beginner questions). Instead, they often return some newer duplicate questions with half-assed answers without any indication there exists a canonical question with superior answers. If there is a technique to bring the old (canonical) questions to light, it could be included in the answer.

Comment: @chivracq the thing about finding the right keywords is that typically they're just a matter of knowing *what things are properly called*, which in turn depends on *learning the material properly in the first place*. Textbooks and courses should, IMHO, never sacrifice this kind of accuracy for expediency.

Comment: @PeterMortensen search engines allow for specifying a date range for searches, but I don't know exactly how it interacts with how Stack Overflow timestamps the pages. You're right that this sort of thing is a problem; one great way to improve the site (if you have a gold badge and close-vote privileges) is to take a canonical that you already know about, try to search for it with a search engine, and hammer anything appropriate (use discretion!) that you find along the way.

Comment: @Voo: I've used SO's own search when I want to find exact text *that was in a code block*, e.g. `code:(%rax)` to find that exact text including non-word characters like `()` and `%`.  That's rare, and most often if I remember a certain Q&A and want to find it again.  Or specific syntax that a duplicate would probably contain. Other use-cases for SO search are filtering on a tag name whose words could often appear in regular text about other things, although that's rare.  Or `user:me` to find my own posts, although luckily my last name is rare so google does well finding it.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I doubt the search engine is doing that. It's more likely that it's simply due canonical have a bunch of unrelated keywords associated with them, which may hurt their ranking. Search "thank you site:stackoverflow.com" and then search what you think should be the keywords for the top questions. You will see how the top results for "thank you" rank lower for those keywords.

Comment: Not just quotation marks but all meta characters eg "-" and ":".

Comment: @Braiam; I am ***not*** implying there is a date filter, just that it can be very difficult to find the canonical even when it is very clear that there *must* exist a question from 2008 or 2009 for some very basic beginner-level question.

Comment: Example: [Running a newly C or C++ program compiled on Unix-like systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221185/), in some cases (older systems only?) by the [default name ***"a.out"***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119409/). This took a long time to find. A question from 2008 had to exist. The search engines would, e.g., rather return one 8 years younger, [from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32337643/how-can-i-run-a-c-program-on-mac-os-x-using-terminal) (this example is not too bad, but it is still a mega duplicate).

Comment: Cont'—A [less stellar duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900151/what-is-this-a-out-file-and-what-makes-it-disappear#comment125829016_41900151).

Comment: Re *"add a negated version (e.g. -uninteresting_word)"*: This may also happen *unintentional* and inadvertently, and it may result in false negative search results. E.g., searching for the command-line option [`-Wunused-value`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wunused-value) may ***not*** find it whereas leaving the "-" out of the search, `Wunused-value`, may... Ask me how I know.

Answer (score 28):

In addition to [dan1st's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419429/211627), I would add one more general tip:

**Searching is like fishing:** you usually don't get what you are looking for on the first cast. If you didn't find anything useful on the first try, then make an incremental change and try again. Add the function name, take away distracting search terms (especially anything that's too unique to your code, like a function name you wrote or a path on your server), wrap or unwrap the error message in quotes, add the language name, try a different search engine, or anything else that occurs to you. Keep experimenting.

**The key to resilience when searching is to set reasonable expectations.** You are probably going to spend a while at it, so settle in and don't get frustrated if the first or tenth article "doesn't work". Pace yourself. Give yourself time.

The goal should probably **not** be to find a snippet of code that makes everything work the way you want it. That works out sometimes, but not usually.

If you are searching for an answer, it's because you don't understand something. Embrace that! Learn to love learning. **Ignorance will be your constant companion!** You can either fight it, or listen to it and learn.

No matter how many years of experience you have, you will always be working with limited knowledge. When you are experiencing a perplexing problem, take it as an opportunity to educate yourself. Learn about the technology you are working with. Don't stop at the first answer... keep going until you have gained some insight and wisdom into the many different ways you *could* accomplish your goal. Only then will you begin to understand *why* you should use one approach over another for your specific case. And then you will not only have solved the problem, but you will have made yourself more valuable to your community and your employer.

If you copy-and-paste something from the internet *without understanding it*, then **you are robbing from your future self.** You might solve an immediate problem, but you have no wisdom to carry forward. You haven't grown as an engineer; you haven't improved.

I have about 20 years of experience in software development and a good chunk of that is in web development. I had to re-configure a Docker container for the first time in my life a few days ago and it took some effort. So I settled in and started learning all I could and, as I researched each thing I encountered (whether I thought I understood it or not), over the course of most of a day, the way forward became clearer to me. I'm not an expert by any stretch, but I know more than I did two weeks ago, and now I know enough to manage that one small part of my company's architecture. And I will build on that knowledge the next time I need to do a similar task.

In short:

> **"*never give in, never give in, never, never, never, never — in nothing, great or small, large or petty — never give in except to convictions of honour and good sense*"**
>
> Winston Churchill
> October 29, 1941
> Harrow School

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the answers of @JDB and @dan1st, I wanted to add a (literally) philosophical note.

The process of starting with a question, searching, learning how to ask it better, searching again, etc. is somewhat similar to the notion of [Hermeneutic circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutic_circle).

[image]

This concept states, more or less, that the text (of an answer) is only understood in the context of the question one has in mind. Once you read the text, you have a better / different question in mind. Rereading the text creates new understandings which lead to new questions, etc.

This notion of Hermeneutic circles precedes Stack Overflow and modern search engines by a bit - it was originally proposed in the 4th century AD.

Comment: Fascinating: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWnA7nZO4EY

Comment: This is an excellent starting point. Search keywords should evolve as you learn to pair and order them better to better describe what you are looking for. And then experience comes into play because eventually you will learn to pick the right search phrase quicker, especially based on what results you get. Sometimes results are way off base which means you need to ask a drastically different question. While other times the results are in the ballpark which means finetuning is in order.

Answer (score 10):

As a mid-level developer, I often know what the "shape" of an answer should look like, before I begin searching. This is helpful, but sometimes leads me astray. If after 30 minutes of searching for a particular type of answer I am unsuccessful, I try to re-evaluate why I think an answer needs to fit a particular shape I've defined. I usually discover that one of my assumptions about the problem is incorrect, and I head back to the drawing board to better scope my question.

Answer (score 10):

Documentation and manuals are easy to understand. It's better to spend time, search the documentation first, understand the concept and do it right the first time than to make a mess and search every error or trouble you get into. In the long run, you're saving time and not wasting it. If you don't understand a specific part of the documentation, you can search for specific keywords and tags.

For example, *if* you're having trouble with [cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors),

- First search the relevant documentation like [this](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol) or [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).
- If you don't understand a specific part of the documentation, you can search the keyword or the documentation URL. I don't see many using this search feature. But you can search: `url:https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ffetch.spec.whatwg.org%2F%23http-new-header-syntax) in Stack Overflow. This will filter in relevant answers and code samples.
- You can also search using `inurl` in your favorite search engine like: `Headers inurl:cors`.
- then read up on that tag's [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors?tab=Frequent)

Comment: Hum, the "best part" of your Answer is that `Frequent` Tab on your [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors?tab=Frequent) Link for any Tag, I had never really noticed/tried it, but that's a good Tip, at least for "large" Tags...: Read 10 Threads a day and become (nearly) an Expert in the Tag in 1 week...!

Answer (score 6):

Don't just click on titles that match *exactly* what you are looking for.

Also open titles that look *similar*, it will open up new possibilities:

- You will learn how to refine your search terms to steer the results in the direction of what you are looking for.
- Use the "Related" list of questions to find results you did not even think of searching for.

Answer (score -9):

A 2023 Modern answer to this question is to use **AI** tools like **ChatGPT** and/or **Microsoft Bing AI Chatbot**. And tell them to search from StackOverflow.

I often use **Bing AI** because it uses a combination of *web search results* and **GPT-4** technology. You can access the **Bing AI Chatbot** (which is free) from the **Microsoft Edge browser** or from *Windows 11 AI Copilot*.

You can also use keywords on Google search just like others described above.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to search Stack Overflow specifically. (Compare with the other answer which explains how to use Google but only return SO results.)

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please don't misunderstand me.