# Code searching at the end of 2022

Tags: discussion, search, code

Tl;Dr:

As of November 2022, is Google still the best option to search for posts including specific code methods?

---

I'm trying to find questions with code generated by the Google Sheets Macro Recorder. OPs do not always mention that the code was generated using this tool. It could be "detected" as the automatically generated code very commonly has a lot of lines as the following examples:

```
spreadsheet.getRange(hardcode_a1Notation_reference).activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula(hardcoded_formula);
```

Another pattern

```
var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
```

I tried

- [[google-sheets] code:activate()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D%20code%3Aactivate%28%29&searchOn=3) 55 results

  - some results don't include `activate`, but not the parenthesis, and others include variants of  the `activate` word, like `active` not in code blocks / inline code.
- [[google-sheets] code:"activate()"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D%20code%3A%22activate%28%29%22&searchOn=3) 24 results

  - includes results having `activate()` in inline code without having nothing else before or after
- [[google-sheets] activate()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D%20activate%28%29&searchOn=3) 1,627 results

  - No surprises: a lot results include variants of `activate` like `active`
- [[google-sheets] "activate()"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D%20%22activate%28%29%22&searchOn=3) 337 results

  - A bit surprised as expected for exact / verbatim matches, a lot results include variants of `activate` like `active`

---

[A comment from 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289671/how-to-search-for-dollar-sign-or-exclamation-mark/331866#comment331126_289671) suggest to use an "insecure" website.

[Replace the built-in Elastic Search with results from Google instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254093/1595451) from 2014 and other more recent posts suggest that Google is better.

Related

- [Why aren't we told we can use special characters in search?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/1595451) from 2017
- [Search not finding methods in code searched for by name](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350767/1595451) from 2017
- [Tips for searching effectively on Stack Overflow - novice developer training](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419427/1595451) from July 2022

---

After reading the Makoto's answer instead of searching around `activate()` I tried searching a single line of code double-quote enclosed using Google:

```
"var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();"
```

then clicking on "more results from stackoverflow.com", that automatically adds `site:stackoverflow.com` as expected. For an early approximation is good enough but the results apparantly were very similar (I didn't compared result by result, and didn't discarted "false positives").

Google returned 32 results including one from ru.stackoverflow.com

[code:"var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22var%20currentCell%20%3D%20spreadsheet.getCurrentCell%28%29%3B%22&searchOn=3) returned 35 results

Both searches were done practically at the same time.

---

I just thought about code plagiarism checkers, so I tried to search

```
code plagiarism checker
```

The results includes several entries that looks interesting, but I will explore them later.

---

The following question includes four instances of `spreadsheet.getRange(something).activate();`, where `something` is `'K1'`, `'N1'`, `'P1'`, in code blocks but it's not  included in the search results of `[google-sheets] code:"activate()"`:

- [GOOGLE script 'copyTo values only' does not work when the source is a function (e.g. NOW())](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808197/1595451)

Another missing question in the previous search

- [How to step through google script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50776248/1595451)

Comment: Yes. On-site search is still generally worthless

Comment: Whoever is in charge of implementing search on SO could just search SO to find out how to do it correctly ... oh wait, never mind.

Comment: Are there only two options? Aren't there some specialised search engines?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Are you aware of another option worthy to mention / explore? Do you have any suggestion about how to search for SO questions? How about searching for multiple lines of code?

Comment: @PeterMortensen added a "progress update"

Comment: @Rubén: There was one, once [mentioned in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=SymbolHound) [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32879/is-it-possible-to-search-for-punctuation-special-characters/113461#113461) [places](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67704/how-to-search-and-or-on-stackoverflow/113531#113531) [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113531), but it [stopped working in April 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32181/how-can-i-search-for-a-string-containing-a-colon/114629#comment1264042_114629).

Comment: Here is [a list of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828654/programmer-friendly-search-engine/1884984) (requires more than 10,000 reputation points to see). I don't know how obsolete the list is.

Comment: The whole idea behind Stack Overflow is to essentially be the top X search results when you do a web search. Readily available answers. It is not intended to be a replacement for the web, so it makes little sense to do a search specifically on stack overflow. The built-in site search has more use to finding stuff to write an answer for rather than to find answers to a problem you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Google Search is vastly more effective in finding things mostly related to code snippets.